# XML tags not properly closed in PHP foreach

Tags: php, xml, foreach, xml-parsing

I'm using a foreach to generate ArticoloPrenotazione nodes, but the result is not as expected and every node close at the end. There's a way to solve this problem?

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

$product = $item_data->get_product();
$product_id = $product->get_id(); 
$item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); 
$barcode = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'barcode', true );
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->addChild('ArticoloPrenotazione', '');
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->ArticoloPrenotazione->addChild('ArticoloBarcode', $barcode);
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->ArticoloPrenotazione->addChild('Quantita', $item_quantity);

 }
```

wrong output

```
<ArticoloPrenotazione>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050677771</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>2</Quantita>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050972647</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>1</Quantita>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050960989</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>1</Quantita>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050961634</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>2</Quantita>
  </ArticoloPrenotazione>
  <ArticoloPrenotazione/>
  <ArticoloPrenotazione/>
  <ArticoloPrenotazione/>
```

expected result

```
<ArticoloPrenotazione>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050677771</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>2</Quantita>
</ArticoloPrenotazione>
<ArticoloPrenotazione>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050972647</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>1</Quantita>
</ArticoloPrenotazione>
<ArticoloPrenotazione>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050960989</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>1</Quantita>
</ArticoloPrenotazione>
<ArticoloPrenotazione>
    <ArticoloBarcode>0000050961634</ArticoloBarcode>
    <Quantita>2</Quantita>
</ArticoloPrenotazione>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are adding the elements...

```
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->addChild('ArticoloPrenotazione', '');
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->ArticoloPrenotazione->addChild('ArticoloBarcode', $barcode);
$xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->ArticoloPrenotazione->addChild('Quantita', $item_quantity);
```

The first line creates the new element - but the second two should add their values to this new node.  As you use `articoli->ArticoloPrenotazione->addChild()`, it will default to adding these to the first `<ArticoloPrenotazione>` node (as you see).  To add them to the new node you can do this by storing the return from the first `addChild()` and adding the new nodes to that...

```
$newNode = $xml->Body->AddPrenotazione->articoli->addChild('ArticoloPrenotazione', '');
$newNode->addChild('ArticoloBarcode', $barcode);
$newNode->addChild('Quantita', $item_quantity);
```